# Translation between different tokenizers

Tags: neural-network, nlp, tokenize, bert-language-model

Sorry if this question is too basic to be asked here. I tried but I couldn't find solutions.

I'm now working on an NLP project that requires using two different models (BART for summarization and BERT for QA). I want to concatenate the two models so that I can train them at the same time instead of separately. However, the two models use different tokenizers. Is there a way to create a layer mapping the output of the first layer to the second one? Would creating a dictionary by hand (mapping every single available value of the tokenizer) work?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you want to train.Tokenizer or BART or BERT?

Comment: Do you have the problem with "Using two tokenizers instead of one" or "Just how to concat one model after another?". Your problem is not clear actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear whether you are asking "How to translate one tokenizers output into another ones output","How to use same tokenizer on both models" or "How to link one model after other for training". So I will answer covering both cases.

Before giving a direct answer to your question, lets have a look into your ML model.

I think this is the model you want to build (correct me in comment section if I am wrong)

```
                                                         |
                                                         |
                                                         Q
                                                         |
         ,-------------------,                    ,-------------,
--text-->|  BART (summarize) |--summarized text-->|  BERT (QA)  |---> A
         `-------------------`                    `-------------`
```

OK, this would be little easy if you have basic idea on Tokenizers and machine learning pipe lines.

I assume you are using huggingface library (even if not there won't be a significant difference) . When we are training an NLP model, we have to tokenize them first.

What do the tokenizers do?

Actually, a tokenizer also has been gone through a training process. It learns how ti break sentences and words into chunks. After that it automatically builds a mapping for each identical chunk. `chunk--> digit/array`.

Lets get the first case

It's literally no. As I mentioned above Tokenizers also were trained. It tokenizes sentences/words according to its own rules and assign numbers according to it's own mapping. The same sentence/word can be broken into different no of chunks at different places by different tokenizers. So , It's not possible to do something like finding french meaning of an English word using dictionary.

The second case

When training the transformer (BART/BERT or any transformer derivative) we pass the result into the transformer. Because of transformers only accept vectors/tensors/matrices , not strings. And then transformer is trained on that input. So you must remember five things.

1. Transformer's output/training depends on input
2. Input depends on Tokenizer's output
3. So, Transformer's output/training depends on Tokenizer
4. Each tokenizer has different mappings. (Output is different for same text)
5. Each tokenizer has different output vertor size.
6. So Once a Transformer has trained along with a specific tokenizer, It can only use that tokenizer.

Can you use same tokenizer, It depends on are you using pre-trained bart and bert or train them from scratch. If you use pretrained ones, you have to use specific tokenizer with it. (If you are using huggingface models, the compatible tokenizer name has been given). Otherwise you can use same tokenizer without any problem. You just have to use same tokenizer for transformers training session only if both transformers have input size equal to output vector of the tokenizer. But after that you can't use other tokenizers.

Lets move to the third case.

Of course you can train both at once. But you have to build an ML pipeline first. It's not very difficult. But you have to learn how to build pipelines first. Many libraries provide facilities to build pipelines easily..

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was trying to ask all these three questions. I'll try to build an ML pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar question as yours when I want to search the prompt with BERT and input the results to LLaMa, which has a totally different tokenizer. Actually, you can check out this blog post: https://tamuhey.github.io/tokenizations/ and the GitHub repo https://github.com/explosion/tokenizations

Using the *tokenizations.get_alignments(tokens_a, tokens_b)*, you can get a mapping between different tokenizers and there is no need to build a dict from scratch. I hope this help!